# Changing speed of an object

Tags: collision-detection, physics, rigid-body-dynamics, rigidbody

Is there a way of changing speed of an object at certain time? I want to change my speed to my initial speed after colliding with any object. I have already added bounce Physics to my colliding objects and player object with Friction set to 0. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Rigidbody component. Then change the velocity value.

```
Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void ChangeSpeed()
{
     rb.velocity = new vector3(x,y,z); //place your value in xyz
}
```

For further reference:
[Unity Physics Rigidbody Velocity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a force opposite to it for decceleration or a force in the movement direction for acceleration.

### Example:

for acceleration:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * FORCE_CONSTANT);
```

or for desceleration:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-transform.forward * FORCE_CONSTANT);
```